# How to make a pointer struct member behave like an array?

Tags: c, visual-c++, c99

I have a pointer in my struct.

```
typedef struct AnotherStructure
{
    int member1;
} AnotherStructure;

typedef struct Structure
{
    int member1;
    AnotherStructure* member2;
} Structure;

AnotherStructure x = {0};
```

This pointer should not behave like a normal pointer but instead should behave like an array. Now I have another piece of code,

```
Structure some_struct = {10, {&x, NULL /* Sentinel */}};
```

This doesn't work. I know why. It's because it's trying to initialize a pointer but fails to do so because the first element is neither a pointer nor an address and because we're providing it multiple initializers. But I also tried,

```
AnotherStructure* array[] = {&x, NULL};
Structure some_struct = {10, array};
```

This also doesn't work because there are different indirections (`AnotherStructure**` to `AnotherStructure*`).

Now I can't actually change the main structure. What I can do is provide different inputs to the Structure initialization. Is there way to do that?

Comment: Try `long array[] = {20, 30};` instead. And lets hope that the life-time of the array is at least as long as the life-time of the structure.

Comment: error C2099: initializer is not a constant

Comment: This is what it is showing now

Comment: `AnotherStructure* array[] = {&x, NULL};` / `Structure some_struct = {10, array};` does not work because the types are wrong, not because initializers must be constant. If you want `membe2` to be a pointer to `AnotherStructure`, then it must be initialized with a pointer to `AnotherStructure`, not with a pointer to pointers to `AnotherStructure`. Show a real example of the actual structure you want to create.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Sorry for confusion, that was a reply to Some programmar dude. My actual error is the one you described

Answer (score 3):

You can use a compound literal:

```
Structure some_struct = {10, (AnotherStructure []) { {20}, {30} }};
```

and also:

```
AnotherStructure x[] = { {20}, {30} };
Structure some_struct = {10, x};
```

The syntax `(type) { list of initial values }` creates an object. In the case above, it creates an array of `AnotherStructure`, and that array is automatically converted to a pointer, which is suitable for initializing the `member2` member. (Since each element of the array is a structure, the initial values for the member inside the structure are enclosed in braces.)

When used outside any function, the object will be static; its lifetime will last the duration of program execution. Inside a function, it will have automatic storage duration. Its lifetime will end when execution of its associated block ends.

Comment: Can edit your post to answer the edited question accordingly.

Comment: @ShreyanAvigyan: I have edited, but you should be aware it is generally inappropriate to edit Stack Overflow questions in a way that renders existing answers incorrect.

Comment: Ok. And also you have created an RHS value here. Is this possible using existing LHS values?

Comment: `Structure some_struct = {10, (AnotherStructure []) { {20}, {30} }};` if the `some_struct` has static storage duration it is not portable as it is the GCC extension.

Comment: @0___________: That is strictly conforming C code; it does not use GCC extensions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  `As a GNU extension, GCC allows initialization of objects with static storage duration by compound literals (which is not possible in ISO C99 because the initializer is not a constant). It is handled as if the object were initialized only with the brace-enclosed list if the types of the compound literal and the object match. The elements of the compound literal must be constant. If the object being initialized has array type of unknown size, the size is determined by the size of the compound literal.` https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html

Comment: @0___________: The code shown does not initialize the object with a compound literal. The fact there is a compound literal inside an expression does not mean the expression is a compound literal. The object is initialized with an address constant.

Comment: @EricPostpischil if one of the initializers is not a constant expression then the whole initializer is not the constant expression.  example: https://godbolt.org/z/564xbeY5z . `The object is initialized with an address constant.` it is not an address constant.

Comment: @0___________: The initializer is a constant expression. C 2018 6.6 7 says that constant expressions in initializers may be address constants, and 6.6 9 says an  address constant may be a pointer to an lvalue designating an object of static storage duration. `(AnotherStructure []) { {20}, {30} }` is, after automatic conversion of the array to a pointer, a pointer to an object of static storage duration. So it is an address constant, so it is a constant expression for purposes of initialization. Further, I compiled it with extensions disabled with no complaint.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
long x = 20, y = 30;
long array[] = {x, y};
Structure some_struct = {10, array};
```

You just need to make sure that `some_struct.member2` is not dereferenced after the lifetime of `array` ends (i.e. after `array` goes out of scope).

Comment: The problem here is I can't show my real code. This is a dummy code right here. I'll edit the question to make it a little bit more clear.

Comment: Can edit your post to answer the edited question accordingly.